# What is the optimal bandwidth in this problem

Tags: nonparametric, convergence, asymptotics

Suppose that I have some estimator $\hat f$ for the parameter $f$. I obtain the following convergence rate $$E\|\hat f - f\|^2 = O\left(\frac{1}{nh} + \frac{1}{nh^2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}h} + h^{2}\right)$$ where $h$ is a bandwidth parameter. How can I discuss what is the optimal value of the bandwidth parameter? Is it interpretable in terms how fast should $h\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$?

In the density estimation I have $E\|\hat f - f\|^2 = O\left(\frac{1}{nh} + h^4\right)$, so it is easy to discuss the optimal bandwidth. Taking first-order conditions, we can see that, we need $h\sim n^{-1/5}$ and so $E\|\hat f - f\|^2\sim n^{-4/5}$.

Comment: "How fast $h\to 0$ and $n\to \infty$" makes no sense in light of the definitions of convergence and $O()$. What exactly do you mean by "discuss" the convergence once you have given it in $O()$ form? What is an "FOC"?

Comment: I meant optimal convergence rates in terms of optimally selected bandwidth sequence.

Comment: So you are considering $h=h(n)$ as a function of $n$ and, among all such functions, you seek to make the right hand side as small as possible (asymptotically) as $n\to \infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be evident from the expressions that the optimal solution will be of the form $h = h(n) = n^\alpha$, because then all four terms become powers of $n$.  (Details are given below.)  Written in this form they become

$$ O\left(\frac{1}{nh} + \frac{1}{nh^2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}h} + h^{2}\right) =  O\left(n^{-1-\alpha} + n^{-1-2\alpha} + n^{-1/2-\alpha} + n^{2\alpha}\right).$$

The asymptotics will be the best possible when the *largest* of these exponents is as small as possible, because it will asymptotically dominate the others. We seek therefore to minimize

$$\max\{-1-\alpha, -1-2\alpha, -1/2-\alpha, 2\alpha\}$$

An easy way to solve this minimax problem is to graph these four (linear) functions of $\alpha$.   Clearly we will need $\alpha\lt 0$ (so that $h$ decreases as $n$ grows), allowing us to limit the plot to small negative $\alpha$:

[image: Figure]

*Blue, red, green, and gold correspond to the four exponents in the order listed.*

By shading the points beneath the four curves (all of which are dominated by at least one of the curves), we reveal the optimum as the *lowest unshaded point* in the plane.  It occurs where $-1/2-\alpha = 2\alpha$, whence $\alpha=-1/6$ is the unique solution.  The four exponents are

$$\{-1-\alpha, -1-2\alpha, -1/2-\alpha, 2\alpha\} = \{-5/6, -2/3, -1/3, -1/3\}$$

(The last two constraints are the active ones; the first two constraints are not relevant.)  Their maximum is $-1/3$.  (The point $(-1/6, -1/3)$ is shown as a black dot in the figure.)  The optimal convergence rate is

$$O(n^{-1/3}).$$

---

(Edit)

Why should the optimal solution have the form $n^\alpha$?  In general all we know is that it should be of the form $n^\alpha f(n)$ where, as $n\to\infty$, either $f(n)/n^\beta \to 0$ or $f(n)/n^\beta \to \infty$ for any $\beta\ne \alpha$.  An improvement is possible if $f(n) = o(n)$; that is, if $f(n)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

The foregoing analysis shows that the two terms controlling the optimum are the last two, so let's consider how $f$ might affect them:

$$O(\ldots + n^{-1/2}/h(n) + h(n)^2) = O(n^{-1/2}n^{-\alpha}/f(n) + n^{2\alpha}f(n)^2) \\ = O\left(n^{-1/3}\left(\frac{1}{f(n)} + f(n)^2\right)\right).$$

If $f(n)=o(n)$, the first term becomes arbitrarily large, demonstrating it is not possible to improve on the solution $h(n)=n^{-1/6}$.

Comment: How do you see that the optimal value is $h=n^\alpha$? If I take a standard approach, differentiating the rate with respect to the bandwidth $h$, I obtain a quadratic equation $2h^4 - (n^{-1} + n^{-1/2})h - 2n^{-1} = 0$, which might have complex and negative roots.

Comment: @Laimond I added a few lines demonstrating why this must be the case.  I do not understand what you mean by a "standard approach" and "complex and negative roots": you seem not to be considering asymptotic behavior. Assuming your equation is correct and plugging in $h=n^\alpha$ gives $O(0)=O(2n^{4\alpha}-n^{-1+\alpha}-n^{-1/2+\alpha}-2n^{-1})=O( 2n^{4\alpha}-n^{-1/2-\alpha})$ (because $\alpha\lt 0$), leading to $\alpha=-1/10$, which clearly is not optimal.